# zend framework 2 not finding classes

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

I'm having an issue where zend framework is not finding a zend json class.

In my index controller I have the line:

```
use Zend\Json\Server\Server;
```

In my index action when I try to create an instance of the json server class with the line:

```
$server = new Server();
```

I get the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Zend\\Json\\Server\\Server' not found in /home/jonathan/code/issacrest/module/Application/src/Controller/IndexController.php on line 38
```

The error itself proves that the framework knows I'm trying to create an instance of the json server class so what gives?

Comment: update your composer.phar,

Comment: try with use \Zend\Json\Server\Server;

Comment: tried that and still the same.  This just makes no sense because the include paths are correct, the files are in place, it should work?!?

Comment: Is your framework fully autoload via the autoload file ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you’re using Composer to manage your project’s dependencies, you have to install [zend-json-server package](https://packagist.org/packages/zendframework/zend-json-server):

```bash
composer require zendframework/zend-json-server
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I have the entire zend framwork, its in my include path for the site php_value include_path "/ZendFramework-2.4.9/library:/ZendFramework-2.4.9" and the zend-json-server files are there, I've checked.

Answer (score 0):

I feel rather foolish for this one.  My project was simply not looking at the correct copy of the zend framework.  I installed the complete framework using composer and it works now.  Thanks for your time